# How to redirect all users who type a particular URL of my website regardless of the cAsE they type?

Tags: php, url, redirect, header, meta

Consider this example:

I have a website called www.mycoolwebsite.com, and I have got a special directory named specialdirectory under the root, and I would like to redirect all the visitors who type:

www.mycoolwebsite.com/specialdirectory

www.mycoolwebsite.com/SpecialDirectory

www.mycoolwebsite.com/SPEciALdIRectOry

www.mycoolwebsite.com/speCIalDIrecToRy

I mean, irrespective of what 'cAsE' they use, I would like to redirect all the traffic to the same location: www.mycoolwebsite.com/specialdirectory

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers. :)

Comment: Have you tried using [htaccess files](https://perishablepress.com/case-insensitive-redirectmatch/)?

Comment: No, please let me know how to use them.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html ... with the [NC] flag

Comment: I've only really edited examples to suit my needs, not that experienced with them. Try having a google for any tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need use .htaccess file in your root site witn [NC] flag. Try some like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mycoolwebsite.com/specialdirectory [R=301,L,NC]
```